# Resolve compiler package installation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm following this tutorial to package MATLAB standalone application into docker images

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler/package-matlab-standalone-applications-into-docker-images.html

I have installed the `compiler SDK` for `MATLAB` but when i execute the folowing command:

```
res = compiler.build.standaloneApplication('mymagic.m', 'TreatInputsAsNumeric', true)
```

I get the following error

> Unable to resolve the name compiler.build.standaloneApplication.

As you can see in the attached image the MATLAB autocomplete shows that the `compiler SDK` contains `package` and `runtime` installed but not the `build` option which is weird. Any thoughts on how can I install it?

[image]

Comment: possibly has to do with MATLAB versions?

Comment: i'm using the latest version of MATLAB R2020a

Comment: The latest version (and the document linked) is R2020b, but I am not sure this is any different. I dont have any other suggestion other than check the versions of matlab runtime and docker etc (section Prerequesites)

Comment: Installing R2020b...

Comment: Installing R2020b did the trick.